# Correct play template files are showing validation error in Scala IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, playframework-2.3, scala-ide

I have installed latest release of scala IDE *(Build id: 4.1.0-vfinal-20150525-1102-Typesafe)* to work on my playframework *(version 2.4)* project. I am able to compile my project and its running as expected but play template files inside the views folder with extension .scala.html is showing validation error (red underlines at some places) in scala IDE that is marking my complete project with red cross symbol.

[image]

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this issue if not can we disable these error warnings? I tried to disable validation through eclipse setting **(project -> right click -> properties -> validation -> suspend all validators)** but it doesn't work.

P.S: For now I am ignoring these errors and editing *.scala.html files in sublime text editor.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed of Scala IDE (Build id: 4.2.0-vfinal-2015-09-25T11:10:29Z-Typesafe)

On the html source -> right click -> Preferences…

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPGV6.png)

General -> Editors -> Structured Text Editors -> 【Appearance】-"Report problems as type" will check to OFF

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzEoZ.png)

Project -> Clean…

that's all

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with all recent builds of scala ide. I temporarily solved the problem by using an old version (kepler) of the scala ide. But not a definitive solution.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: For those who are voting deletion on this post, a **temporary** solution **is** a **solution**.

Comment: Please add more detail and separate the text into paragraphs to avoid getting it deleted.